# Cannot run executable JAR file on another PC

Tags: java, jar

I have a Java application exported into the executable JAR file, which I run from a Windows Forms app (via java -jar).

The solution works perfectly fine on my PC, but it won't run on other PCs. There is literally no output after running the JAR, no exception, no logs from log4j, the command line window closes without displaying anything.

I have:

- confirmed that all paths used in both applications are relative
- made sure the other PCs are using the same Java version
- made sure that all required input files are in place
- made sure the MANIFEST.mf is correct
- tried running the JAR from command line - no output again
- run the application with admin account
- rebuilt the JAR several times

I have no ideas left at this point. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

EDIT: the JAR was made in Eclipse on Windows 7. The other PCs I tried this on all have Windows 7 or 10. I do not use JavaFX or Swing, it is a purely console-based application.

Comment: Have you tried running JAR printing simple "hello world" on both machines? What was the effect?

Comment: So when you call `java -jar ...` from a terminal window, it just terminates? Did you check the PCs not only have the same Java version installed but that your call _really_ uses the same version? Did you try adding a `System.out.println` right at the start of your application for debugging purposes, e.g. to exclude any problems with log4j?

Comment: @Zimny Lech please add more detail. (on which os you are trying to execute the jar. if it is a javafx application, etc..)

Comment: @Pschemo I made a different executable JAR before, and I confirmed that it works on all PCs with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting I found the answer:

When calling the JAR from WinForms, I was passing a file path as argument. I didn't put `\"` at the beginning and end of the argument, so passing a path containing one or more spaces resulted in a wrong number of arguments.

It just so happened that the project path on my first PC didn't contain any spaces, that's why it worked there.